# How to Restrict user to select single selection from Multiple selection List Box in Infopath 2010

Tags: infopath

I'm using Infopath 2010 and created form with Multiple Selections in List Box. I want to restrict users to single selection only. How do i acheive this without any coding.  I'm from non-technical person. Just working on some process efficiency using Infopath.

Answer (score 0):

Should the item only ever have one selection? You could simply change the field to not allow multiple values from within SharePoint. Easiest way to make sure the form updates properly after the change is to adjust the field in the library on SharePoint, then select the 'Customize Form' button to start editting the infopath form -- it should prompt you that the field definitions have changed and you need to update them.

Comment: Hi John, yes, Item will have one selection ever. I thought of doing so but i have created some rules and conditions to autofill employee name using Infopath. If i use the sharepoint form to change the settings and load it again in Infopath will the previously created rules and conditions will purge off or will stay same.. As i said i'm not from technical background so not sure of these things.

Comment: @kumarchenna The original control you created in your infopath form will no longer work, however it will remain available on the form, so you could copy all of the rules from the old control (multiple value) to the new control (dropdown or combobox probably) using the 'manage rules' pane -- then you would just need to delete the old multivalue control